# Extension Method that accepts delegate function

Tags: c#, delegates, extension-methods

I'm still trying to wrap my head around delegate functions and extension methods. I have created an extension method for `DropDownList`. I'd like to pass the function to be called in my extension method but I'm getting an error `Argument type 'IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Func<IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>>'`

```
public static class DropDownListExtensions {
    public static void populateDropDownList(this DropDownList source, Func<IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> delegateAction) {
        source.DataValueField = "Key";
        source.DataTextField = "Value";
        source.DataSource = delegateAction;
        source.DataBind();
    }
}
```

being called like so...

```
myDropDownList.populateDropDownList(getDropDownDataSource());
```

getDropDownDataSource signature...

```
protected IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>> getDropDownDataSource() {
    StateInfoXmlDocument stateInfoXmlDocument = new StateInfoXmlDocument();
    string schoolTypeXmlPath = string.Format(STATE_AND_SCHOOL_TYPE_XML_PATH, StateOfInterest, SchoolType);
    var nodes = new List<XmlNode>(stateInfoXmlDocument.SelectNodes(schoolTypeXmlPath).Cast<XmlNode>());
    return nodes.Distinct().Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Attributes["area"].Value, x.Attributes["area"].Value)).OrderBy(x => x.Key);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should remove the `()` after `getDropDownDataSource` when calling:

```
myDropDownList.populateDropDownList(getDropDownDataSource);
```

EDIT: Method groups can be implicitly converted to delegates with a compatible signature. In this case `getDropDownDataSource` matches the signature of `Func<IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>>` so the compiler applies the conversion for you, effectively doing

```
Func<IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>> func = getDropDownDataSource;
myDropDownList.populateDropDownList(func);
```

Comment: And possibly add it to `source.DataSource = delegateAction` making it `source.DataSource = delegateAction()`

Comment: or use lamba syntax `myDropDownList.populateDropDownList(()=>getDropDownDataSource());`

Comment: Can you explain why `()` makes a difference? How does the compiler interpret `myDropDownList.populateDropDownList(getDropDownDataSource)` as apposed to `myDropDownList.populateDropDownList(getDropDownDataSource())`. Could you add that to your answer, Thanks :)

Comment: One is method group conversion to delegate, one is a method call. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx2bwtw7.aspx

Comment: @asawyer ok so you're saying that one is a delegate and the other is trying to make the method call directly?

Comment: @bflemi3 - I've added an explanation

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in the line `myDropDownList.populateDropDownList(getDropDownDataSource());` you are calling `getDropDownDataSource()` which returs a `IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>`.  So, the compiler is saying that you cannot convert `IOrderedEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,string>>` to the Func.  To pass the Func you could either drop the parenthesis so that you are passing a pointer like this `myDropDownList.populateDropDownList(getDropDownDataSource);` or you can pass the data source code directly:

```
myDropDownList.populateDropDownList(() => {
    StateInfoXmlDocument stateInfoXmlDocument = new StateInfoXmlDocument();
    string schoolTypeXmlPath = string.Format(STATE_AND_SCHOOL_TYPE_XML_PATH, StateOfInterest, SchoolType);
    var nodes = new List<XmlNode>(stateInfoXmlDocument.SelectNodes(schoolTypeXmlPath).Cast<XmlNode>());
    return nodes.Distinct().Select(x => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Attributes["area"].Value, x.Attributes["area"].Value)).OrderBy(x => x.Key);
}
```

But that is a bit ugly. :-)